# Haxe Reference Object via String

Tags: haxe

In Haxe, I am trying to access an object's value via a variable. In JavaScript you use `[ ]` to access it, but in Haxe this doesn't work and comes back with an error:

> String should be Int
>
> Array access is not allowed on { x : Int, name : String }

I need help with the last line of code:

```haxe
var room = { x: 10, name: 'test' };

trace(room.name);   // this works returns 'test' 

// how do I reference foo to return 'test' as the above result.
var foo = "name";
var results = room[foo];   // need fixing
```

Answer (score 7):

What you're trying to do is called [Reflection](http://haxe.org/manual/std-reflection.html), and the way to do that in Haxe is via the [`Reflect`](http://api.haxe.org/Reflect.html) API:

```
var results = Reflect.field(room, "name");
```

If you want to access a `static` field instead, pass the `Class<T>` as the first argument instead of an instance:

```
class Foo {
    public static var bar = 0;
}

var bar = Reflect.field(Foo, "bar");
```

For [properties](https://haxe.org/manual/class-field-property.html) with a getter, you'll want to use [`getProperty()`](https://api.haxe.org/Reflect.html#getProperty) instead.

---

**Note:** Reflection is generally considered bad practice as it moves errors from compile- to runtime and is inherently type-unsafe. There are *usually* better ways to solve a problem, but it's hard to recommend a concrete solution here without more context.

Comment: Brilliant!!!,  I been messing about with this for 2 days now. Perfect, Thanks.  I will bear in mind that I might have to change the way this works in the future to make it more robust, but for the demo version, this will be fine.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You could alternatively use [`haxe.DynamicAccess`](http://api.haxe.org/haxe/DynamicAccess.html).  This is particularly useful if your object is the result of `haxe.Json.parse`, or by other means a `Dynamic`.

However, since your example (indirectly) types `room`, some conversion is needed and you'll still loose typing (you'll have "values" with different types and will need to settle on `<Dynamic>`):

```
    var foo = "name";
    var access = (cast room:haxe.DynamicAccess<Dynamic>);
    trace(access[foo]);
```

([full example](http://try.haxe.org/#E291c))

If your use case has a typed structure that can be converted into a `String -> T` map or if you're already dealing with dynamics, this is a good fit; otherwise, `Reflect` or `untyped` are simpler and therefore better.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the untyped.
eg:

```
var results = untyped room[foo];
```

You just need to be careful when using untyped, as it can lead to runtime errors if you don't put appropriate runtime checks in place.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at both options.

Comment: If you're gonna use Reflection, at least use the `Reflect` API. It's slightly safer than `untyped`, and most importantly _cross-platform_.